# IVP with no solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y'(y + x) - A = 0$, for some $A \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$.

This differential equation has no solution that satisfies $y(0) = 0$.

Is there a way to derive/see this without using an implicit solution?

Also wondering if there is a way to use the existence theorem to show that there is no solution?

Comment: Try plugging in $x=0$ and $y=0$ in the equation.

Comment: I see that this forces $A = 0$, which is a contradiction. But could you perhaps elaborate on why it is allowed to plug $x=0$ and $y=0$ directly in the differential equation?

Comment: Remember that $y$ actually is an abbreviation of $y(x)$ since $y$ is a function. For a function $y$ to satisfy the differential equation, it needs to be true for all values of $x$ in its domain. $y(0)=0$ means that at $x=0$ you have $y=0$. So in particular at $x=0$ the differential equation becomes $A=0$ which contradicts $A\neq0$.

Comment: If you allow a solution $y$ such that $y'(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to0$, then it's possible. For instance, with $a=1$, let $y(x)=-1-x-W(-\exp(-1-x))$. It's a solution on $(0,+\infty)$, that can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$ such that $y(0)=0$. But this $y$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
y'(y + x) - A = 0 \iff y' = \frac{A}{y + x}
$$
By the Picard-Lindelöf theorem the function $\frac{A}{y + x}$ must be Lipshitz continuous (in the 2nd argument, i.e. $y$) on any compact set $V \subset \mathbb R^2$ containing the point $(x,y) = (0,0)$. The last condition is sufficient to have a *unique* solution through that point, I'm not sure if it is necessary as well.